# Second derivative of bump function?

Tags: real-analysis

My question is?

Does there exist a function $f\in C^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ such that

$$\begin{cases}
f\left(x\right) & =1\quad\textrm{when }\left|x\right|<1,\\
f\left(x\right) & =0\quad\textrm{when }\left|x\right|\geq2,\\
f\left(x\right) & \in\left[0,1\right],\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\\
\left|f'\left(x\right)\right| & \leq2,\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\\
\left|f"\left(x\right)\right| & \leq2,,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{cases}$$
Thanks.

Comment: Should there be 1 instead of 2 in $|x|\geq 2$? If not, then what is the definition of $f(x)$ when $x\in [1,2)$?

Comment: My question is to ask about the existence of such a function.

Comment: The naive guess, which is often the best choice under certain constraints because of mean value theorem/Taylor's theorem considerations, is to take an appropriate polynomial on $[-2,-1]$ and $[1,2]$. In this case since you need $C^2$ you have six conditions so it is a quintic spline. This amounts to finding the Newton polynomial for $p(1)=1,p'(1)=0,p''(1)=0,p(2)=0,p'(2)=0,p''(2)=0$. This turns out to be $p(x)=1-(x-1)^3+3(x-1)^3(x-2)-6(x-1)^3(x-2)$.

Comment: (Cont.) This satisfies the derivative condition but fails the second derivative condition (I checked this by plotting, not symbolically). This suggests that you probably cannot achieve the desired result, as you might directly check by mean value theorem type considerations (as in Michael's answer).

Comment: Typo: in the last term of my second-to-last comment it should be $(x-2)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Observation: Since $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=1$, so the first inequality is not strict.  (Alternately, $f^{-1}(1)$ is closed).

Therefore, $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=0$.  So, by the mean value theorem, there is some $c\in(1,2)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2-1}=-1$.

Since $f$ is constant for $|x|<1$ and $|x|>2$ and the first derivative is continuous, $f'(1)=0$ and $f'(2)=0$.

Now, we can see that $c$ above must be $\frac{3}{2}$ since otherwise, if $c<\frac{3}{2}$, then there is some $d$ in $(1,c)$ so that $f'(d)=\frac{f(c)-f(1)}{c-1}=-\frac{1}{c-1}$.  Since $c<\frac{3}{2}$, $c-1<\frac{1}{2}$, so $\frac{1}{c-1}>2$, which contradicts the final assumption.

This last observation can be extended as follows: suppose that $a\in(1,\frac{3}{2})$, then $|f'(a)|\leq 2(a-1)$ since, once again by the mean value theorem, there would be a point $b\in(1,a)$ so that $f''(b)=\frac{f'(a)-f'(1)}{a-1}=\frac{f'(a)}{a-1}$, by the last condition, $\frac{|f'(a)|}{a-1}\leq 2$ and the result follows.

Therefore, we see that $f'(a)\geq -2(a-1)$ for all $a\in(1,\frac{3}{2})$.  Similarly, $f'(a)\geq -2(2-a)$ for all $a\in(\frac{3}{2},1)$.  Moreover, since the given bounds are not differentiable, the inequality must be strict at one point (and hence in a neighborhood of that point).

However, $-1=f(2)-f(1)=\int_1^2 f'(x)dx> \int_1^{3/2} -2(x-1)dx+\int_{3/2}^2 -2(2-x)dx=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}=-\frac{1}{2}$.  This is a contradiction.

I feel like I've made a mistake somewhere (since the argument didn't need to be as tight as I expected it to be), but I can't spot it - let me know if you see a hole!

Comment: That first thing is not actually a problem: it is true that $f^{-1}(\{ 1 \})$ is closed but they said $f(x)=1$ *if* $|x|<1$, not iff. And the other conditions, in particular the third one, do not rule out the existence of other points where $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @Ian Agreed, but I wanted to use the mean value theorem on $x=1$, so I needed to establish a value there.

Comment: Your argument seems OK, in particular it is consistent with the simple heuristic "try the polynomial of least degree such that $p(1)=1,p'(1)=0,p''(1)=0,p(2)=0,p'(2)=0,p''(2)=0$". I find this heuristic often gives the optimal solution to problems of this sort, at least when the constraints are "simple". (Of course it will be highly suboptimal if the bounds fall "much heavier" on some derivatives than others.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose such an $f$ exists. Note that the hypotheses imply $f'(1)=0=f'(2).$ Consider the line connecting $(1,1)$ and $(2,0).$ This line has slope $-1$. Because $f'(1) = 0,$ We have $f(1+h)$ above this line for small $h>0.$ It follows that for any such $h,$the line connecting $(1+h,f(1+h))$ to $(2,0)$ has slope less than $-1.$ That slope, by the mean value theorem, equals $f'(c)$ for some $c\in (1,2).$ Conclusion: $f'(c) < -1$ for some $c\in (1,2).$

Suppose $c\in (1,3/2].$ The mean value theorem then gives

$$|f''(d)| = |\frac{f'(c)-f'(1)}{c-1}| > \frac{1}{c-1}$$

for some $d \in (1,c).$ Because $0<c-1\le 1/2,$ we see $|f''(d)| >2,$ contradiction. A similar argument works if $c\in [3/2,2).$ Thus there can be no such $f.$

Comment: You have a typo in the paragraph between the two indented equations. I guess you meant $(1,3/2]$, or really $(1,3/2)$ given how exactly you chose to use $c$ later on.

Comment: With $c=3/2$ you have $|f''(d)|=2$ by your argument. What happens then?

Comment: Good point! I'll have to fix that soon.