# Construction of bump function with arbitrary choice of bound on second order derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

### Background and problem statement

From distribution theory, it is well known that the function
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}, & |x| \leq 1; \\
0, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is an infinitely differentiable function with compact support.
By direct computation, one can find that
\begin{equation}
f^{(2)}(x) = \begin{cases}
\left[ -\frac{2}{(1-x^2)^2} - \frac{8x}{(1-x^2)^3} + \frac{4x^2}{(1-x^2)^4} \right] e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}, & |x| \leq 1; \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Let
$$ P(x) = -\frac{2}{(1-x^2)^2} - \frac{8x}{(1-x^2)^3} + \frac{4x^2}{(1-x^2)^4}. $$
By ploting out this function, it was found that there are some oscillations near the points $ \pm 1 $, , which are best to be avoided in numerical computation, as shown in the following picture.
[image]
My main question is

> Are there any ways to bound the second derivatives for this particular choice of bump function?

### My research

I have realised that in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743987/control-over-bump-functions-second-derivative), the asker suggested that it is highly unlikely that such bump function proposed in my question has small second order derivatives.
It is also suggested, in the same post, that it is impossible to bound the second order derivative for the alternative bump function proposed in the post.
I have also seen in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975452/second-derivative-of-bump-function) that a particular example of bump function of bounded second derivative does not exists.
However, if one is willing to choose any bump function such that the only requirement is it is at least $C^2$ (in particular, it is not necessary to control the first order derivatives), would it be possible to control the bound over the second order derivatives?

For those of you who are interested in where does this question come from, I am implementing an numerical algorithm for the [EIT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance_tomography), during which I need to construct some testing examples of conductivity (need to be twice differentiable) where it is identically 1 near the boundary of some domain. Bump function seems to be a natural choice of function satisfying such constraint.

Comment: I do not have a solution, but I am curious if you have found an answer to this question.